# Global variable won't change

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a timer to close a modal on an html page. The problem is that I need a global variable to be used in functions, and I can't re-assign a value to this variable.

I've looked for answers on many sites but none of them worked with my code. The value is correctly set when it is declared, but it can't be re-assigned later when I call it in functions (instead of simply reducing it's value).

No errors are detected in the browser's dev-tools.

```
var delayToCloseModal = 5;

function AnimateModal() {

    // Each time this function is called
    delayToCloseModal = 5; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!
                           // delayToCloseModal is not set at 5 again


    // If the modal isn't oppened
    if (document.getElementById("modal").style.opacity < 0.01) {
        // Open Modal
    }


    // Check every second if the timer is done, else reduce it by 1
    var checkTimer = setInterval(CheckCounterDone, 1000);


    function CheckCounterDone() {
        if (delayToCloseModal > 0) {
            // Reduce timer
            delayToCloseModal--; // Strangely, this works really fine!
        }
        else {

            // Stop checking timer
            clearInterval(checkTimer);

            // Close Modal

        }
    }
}
```

The "timer" system works really fine, the modal automatically close 5 seconds after its opening, but if the function is called again when the modal is already open, it won't reset the open timer to 5.

Comment: What happens when the function is called again when the modal is already open? I understand that the open timer isn't being reset, but does the modal still close after 5 seconds?

Comment: Rh16 has a good point in his comment! The open timer is successfully reset, but checktimer is called multiple time, which will decrease multiple times the timer... The modal will close successfully, but after a shorter amount of time. Unfortunately, rh16's code doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem! (It might be "homemade", but it works)

I created a Boolean variable to enable or disable the creation of a setInterval if one is already running. Here is the code :

```
var delayToCloseModal = 5;
var timerRunning = false; // Set false as default value to allow the creation of the first timer

function AnimateModal() {

    // Each time this function is called
    delayToCloseModal = 5; 


    // If the modal isn't oppened
    if (document.getElementById("modal").style.opacity < 0.01) {
        // Open Modal
    }


    // Check if a timer is already running
    if (!timerRunning){
         var checkTimer = setInterval(CheckCounterDone, 1000); // Create new timer
         timerRunning = true; // Forbids to create another new timer
    }


    function CheckCounterDone() {
        if (delayToCloseModal > 0) {
            // Reduce timer
            delayToCloseModal--; 
        }
        else {

            // Stop checking timer
            clearInterval(checkTimer); // Delete the existing timer
            timerRunning = false; // Allow to recreate another timer

            // Close Modal

        }
    }
}
```

The modal now stays opens for 5 seconds since the last call of the function, and the timer is only reduced by one each second, even if you spam the call of the function, and close succesfully after the delay has been set to 0.

Thanks to anyone who has answered for your help! :)